# Japanese/Chinese text in pdf using iText Java

Tags: java, unicode, internationalization, itext

I need to add japanese/chinese text from xml web response to pdf using iText in java. I tried the following code after copying the KozMinPro-Regular.ttf to my c:\WINDOWS\Fonts folder but failed.

`Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont("KozMinPro-Regular", "UniJIS-UCS2-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 10);`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you get an exception, null, the wrong font?

Comment: You need the full path.  In the case of font files with more than one font in them (.ttc) you also need to add a ",1" or ",2" to define which font you want.  PS:  I always prefer "Identity-H".

Answer (score 5):

You should use **[iTextAsian](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/ExtraJars1.0/)** (extra JAR file).

Some description of **[cmap_info.txt](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.0/com/lowagie/text/pdf/fonts/cmap_info.txt)** inside **iTextAsian.jar**.

> Note that whatever value you pass for
>   the 'embedded' parameter  with the
>   method **BaseFont.createFont**, the font
>   WILL NOT BE embedded. To understand
>   why, please read the following
>   information.
>
> The fonts that are used in Acrobat
>   Reader when viewing a PDF file that
>   uses CJK fonts will be downloaded in
>   one or more font packs. You can
>   download these fontpacks yourself from
>   this URL:
>   http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/acrrasianfontpack.html
>
> On this page, you can find the
>   following information: **"If the author
>   of an Adobe (R) Portable Document
>   Format (PDF) file embeds CJK and
>   Central European (CE) fonts in a PDF
>   document, then any language version of
>   Adobe Reader (R) software will be able
>   to display the CJK and CE text on any
>   system without additional software.**
>
> **If the author of the PDF document uses
>   CJK or CE fonts but does not embed
>   them in the document, then the correct
>   fonts will need to be installed in
>   order to view the Adobe PDF file on
>   non-native systems."**

If needed fonts is unembedded in PDF file, you should not use absolute path for font files.
Create a jar file with font files, and include it in classpath entry.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tested this, but according to [this](http://www.ee.e-mansion.com/~egami/iText/) page

Usage of Installed fonts are something like this.

```
Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\KozMinPro-Regular.ttf,1", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 10);
```