# chinese words not coming in pdf, using ITextRenderer

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using ItextRenderer to convert html to pdf, its working for spanish, french words but when I am trying for chinese words its not coming in PDF

```
  ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
  renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
  renderer.layout();
```

I tried adding font but still not working

```
   renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\mingliu.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

   renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\simsun.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

   renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\batang.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

   renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
   renderer.layout();
   OutputStream os = 
   Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("chinese.pdf"));
   renderer.createPDF(os);
```

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462797/converting-html-file-containing-chinese-character-to-pdf-file-using-itext-chine

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage Chinese words, you will need following 3 libraries:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-asian</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

the essential part of the Chinese characters encoding is parsing the html string with correct Asian font, see following as the core code:

```java
    void createPDF(final String content, final String filename) {
        final Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("target", filename)));
            document.open();
            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
            XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
            worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, input, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), new AsianFontProvider());
        } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
            log.error("Failed to generate PDF for {}", filename, e);
        } finally {
            document.close();
        }
    }
    class AsianFontProvider extends XMLWorkerFontProvider {
        @Override
        public Font getFont(final String fontName, final String encoding, final boolean embedded, final float size, final int style, final BaseColor color) {
            try {
                BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                Font font = new Font(bf, size, style, color);
                font.setColor(color);
                return font;
            } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
                log.error("Failed to create font for {} with encoding {}", fontName, encoding, e);
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("incorrect font creation, please check the font parameters", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

for more details, you can visit my github, I created a [mini project](https://github.com/iyunbo/stackoverflow) for this problem:

- source code: https://github.com/iyunbo/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/main/java/org/iyunbo/encoding/Html2Pdf.java
- unit test: https://github.com/iyunbo/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/test/java/org/iyunbo/encoding/Html2PdfTest.java

Answer (score 0):

To view any other languages in PDF,first you need to install that font pack in your system. Itext can easily write any language to your PDF file while generating it, but your system should have that specific font pack to show those fonts.

Comment: If itext embeds the (required subset of the) font, there is no need for any language packs.